# How to find square of individial elements of different sized numpy arrays in the list

Tags: python, numpy

Consider I have following list of np arrays:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
>>> l.append(np.array([[7,8],[9,10]]))
>>> l.append(np.array([[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]))
```

I want to find sum of squares of each individual values of all the numpy arrays in this list. Doing following:

```
>>> np.sum(np.square(l))
```

gives following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,2)
```

How I do this in more pythonic or numpythonic way? Do I have to manually iterate over every numpy array to find their squres and then sum manually, something like below?

```
>>> np.sum(list(map(lambda i: np.sum(np.square(i)),l)))
944
```

**PS:**

For following list

```
>>> l                                     
[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]]), array([[ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])]
```

I am able to do this:

```
>>> np.sum(np.square(np.hstack(l)))  
385
```

But there seems some restrictions on dimensions of input list for `hstack()` to work as it gives similar error on first list.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to manually iterate over every numpy array to find their squres and then sum manually, something like below?

Essentially, yes. You have a list of numpy arrays with incompatible shapes/lengths. This means you step outside of the numpy array model. But your implementation could be a bit smoother:

```
sum(np.sum(np.square(a)) for a in l)
```